# pinescript - problema con redondeo de contratos

Tags: pine-script

Buen dia,
He buscado por todas partes alguna solucion y no la he  conseguido,
Tradingview me lanza el order_contracts siempre en 1 incluso aun cuando no deberia.
mi tipo de cuenta es la pro, las mas economica de todas.

// descripcion
construi un script en de estrategia en tradingview que unicia asi:

```
strategy(shorttitle="RTV", title="provando", overlay=true, 
             calc_on_every_tick=true, pyramiding=0,  currency = currency.USD, precision = 16, 
             initial_capital=14, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)
```

segun lo que he leido con esto le indico que me use el 100% de mi capital en la compra de la cryto, espero no estar equivocado.

como la crypto cuesta mas que el dinero inicial realice este pequeño reajuste para que me determine la cantidad de contratos que quiero adquirir menos un pequeño decimal para evitar el error.

```
orderSize = (strategy.equity / close) - 0.001
```

depues de toda la logica, realizo las entradas y salidas

```
if between_dates and (startLongTrade or startShortTrade)
    strategy.entry("Long",  strategy.long, qty=orderSize,  when = startLongTrade)
strategy.close("Long", qty=orderSize, when = startShortTrade)
```

tradingview me envia un objeto como este a mi servidor

```
{
    "passphrase": "abcdefgh",
    "time": "2022-01-02T17:41:01Z",
    "exchange": "BINANCE",
    "ticker": "DASHUSDT",
    "bar": {
        "time": "2022-01-02T17:41:00Z",
        "open": 142.4,
        "high": 142.4,
        "low": 142.4,
        "close": 142.4,
        "volume": 0.502
    },
    "strategy": {
        "position_size": 0,
        "order_action": "sell",
        "order_contracts": 1,
        "order_price": 142.4,
        "order_id": "Long",
        "market_position": "long",
        "market_position_size": 1,
        "prev_market_position": "flat",
        "prev_market_position_size": 0
    }
}
```

el cual envio a la api a binance pero no entiendo como es que me envia el order_contracts en 1
si estoy enviando el qty en orderSize y este en ese momento valia 0.0976....

ademas ya intente cambiando el valor del initial_capital lo puse en 1600 el ordersize cambio a 11.266.... y aun asi sigue mandando 1

siertamente ya me preocupe.
nececito ayuda.

**Editado:**

claro mi estimado aqui el objeto de como sale de tradingview la informacion al servidor
estoy usando pine v5 sera eso?

```
{
    "passphrase": "abcdefgh",
    "time": "{{timenow}}",
    "exchange": "{{exchange}}",
    "ticker": "{{ticker}}",
    "bar": {
        "time": "{{time}}",
        "open": {{open}},
        "high": {{high}},
        "low": {{low}},
        "close": {{close}},
        "volume": {{volume}}
    },
    "strategy": {
        "position_size": {{strategy.position_size}},
        "order_action": "{{strategy.order.action}}",
        "order_contracts": {{strategy.order.contracts}},
        "order_price": {{strategy.order.price}},
        "order_id": "{{strategy.order.id}}",
        "market_position": "{{strategy.market_position}}",
        "market_position_size": {{strategy.market_position_size}},
        "prev_market_position": "{{strategy.prev_market_position}}",
        "prev_market_position_size": {{strategy.prev_market_position_size}}
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿No será que lo que estás enviando, ese `1` corresponde al 100% y no al número de contratos?

Comment: deacuerdo, y como haria para enviar usar el 100% de mi capital ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace falta más información para ser más específico, solo puedo ayudar listando estas dos posibilidades que es necesario probarlas.

##### Causa posible 1.

- Considero posible que erróneamente envíes `1` correspondiente al 100% del capital en vez de la cantidad de contratos.

Puedes confirmar con [¿Cómo usar un valor variable en la alerta?](https://es.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000531021/) para estar seguro que la variable que enlazas con el objecto de salida corresponde a la variable del número de contratos.

La que veo que mejor encaja es:

> {{strategy.order.contracts}}: devuelve el número de contratos de la
> orden ejecutada.

En lo que he probado, la alarma de la operación lanza correctamente el valor del contrato, contrario al `1` que expone en la pregunta.

##### Causa posible 2.

- En el caso concreto que compartes, resulta que estás tratando de abrir una operación con $14 (capital inicial) lo que daría un número de tipo `float`, posiblemente ignorando el tipo de variable se esté aproximando todo decimal entre 0 y 1 a 1.

Ante la duda de cómo funciona cada parámetro puedes consultar la [documentación oficial: fun_strategy](https://es.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_strategy)
Según [esta parte](https://es.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dpercent_of_equity) efectivamente el `default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100` corresponde a abrir operaciones con el 100% del capital.

Recomiendo:

- Probar con estrategias más simples (código mínimo funcional) para comprobar cada posibilidad, no hace falta compartir el código original ni probarlo con este.
- También utilizar la alarma del navegador para comprobar la salida antes
  de enviarla a algún servidor.

##### Edito:

No consigo replicar el problema, el código de prueba que estoy usando es:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © alfredomaussa

//@version=5
strategy("Mi estrategia", overlay=true,precision=16, pyramiding=0, initial_capital=14, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100,currency=currency.USD)

fastP=input(15)
longP=input(55)

fast=ta.ema(close,fastP)
long=ta.sma(close, longP)

// longCondition = crossover(fast, long)
longCondition = ta.rising(close,1)
// shortCondition = crossunder(fast, long)
shortCondition = ta.falling(close,2)
// var orderSize=1
orderSize = (strategy.equity / close) - 0.001

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long,qty=orderSize)
    // strategy.exit("exit", "My Long Entry Id", profit = 18000, loss = 6000)

if (shortCondition)
    strategy.close("My Long Entry Id")
    // strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
    // strategy.exit("exit", "My Short Entry Id", profit = 18000, loss = 6000)
plot(orderSize)

alert('{"passphrase": "abcdefgh","time": "{{timenow}}","exchange": "{{exchange}}","ticker": "{{ticker}}","bar": {"time": "{{time}}","open": {{open}},"high": {{high}},"low": {{low}},"close": {{close}},"volume": {{volume}}},"strategy": {"position_size": {{strategy.position_size}},"order_action": "{{strategy.order.action}}","order_contracts": {{strategy.order.contracts}},"order_price": {{strategy.order.price}},"order_id": "{{strategy.order.id}}","market_position": "{{strategy.market_position}}","market_position_size": {{strategy.market_position_size}},"prev_market_position": "{{strategy.prev_market_position}}","prev_market_position_size": {{strategy.prev_market_position_size}}}')
```

La alerta del navegador me genera correctamente los valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edite por que no me dejaba pegar el texto muy largo aqui, arriba el objeto que lanzo al servidor, tambien me salto la duda de si es el tipo de ceunta que uso, la mia es la pro mas economica

Comment: tienes razon es mi script de alguna  otra forma modifica los valores no se por que y lo arreglare despues gracias.